# Start R console with an RDS file already loaded into a variable

Tags: r

I have an RDS file, for example `/tmp/data.RDS`. I would like to start R and already have that file loaded into a variable in the environment. I tried:

`R -e "data <- readRDS('/tmp/data.RDS')"`

However, the `-e` parameter exits the console when the command is done.

I also tried:

`R --interactive -e "data <- readRDS('/tmp/data.RDS')"`

Unfortunately, it looks like `--interactive` and `-e` are mutually exclusive -- the first one in the command line will be used, the other one ignored. In other words, this will not run the part after `-e`.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Would adding the call to your .Rprofile be sufficient? Or do you only want to do this one time?

Comment: You can add something like `if (any(commandArgs()=="yes")) data <- readRDS('/tmp/data.RDS')` into your `.Rprofile`. Next, if you open R with a `yes` argument, the file will be loaded; otherwise it will not.

Comment: More context: I have a Ruby object with an `r_data_file` attribute (I use the object to cache R data). I would like to be able to do something like obj.inquire to launch R and load the RDS there. This is for debugging purposes. Ideally I wouldn't want to tweak .Rprofile, though I'll look into that now. Thanks!

Comment: The plot thickens: I updated `Rprofile.site` as per @nicola's suggestion. However, now when I run `R load_rds a=~/tmp/a.RDS`, I get `ARGUMENT 'load_rds' __ignored__` and `ARGUMENT 'a=/home/elad/tmp/a.RDS' __ignored__` on startup. Any way to suppress these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you have two possibilities:

**Solution 1.** Customize your `.Rprofile` to capture the `commandArgs()` vector (see also [nicola's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677305/start-r-console-with-an-rds-file-already-loaded-into-a-variable#comment47492825_29677305)). For example, put this in your `.Rprofile`:

```
if (any(commandArgs()=="load_rds")) {
  l = which(commandArgs()=="load_rds")  
  data = readRDS(commandArgs()[l+1])
}
```

and then start your session with: `R --args load_rds a.rds`

**Solution 2.** This solution is little bit more hacky, but does not require you to modify your `.Rprofile`. You can (a) start a non-interactive R session which loads the data and then ends, and then (b) start an interactive R session that loads your previous workspace. Just type in a console:

```
R --save -e 'data = readRDS("~/a.rds")'; R --restore
```

Does this help?

Comment: Ended up with solution 1. Thank you!